# retrieve gitlab specific folder specific commit

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a gitlab repository and i cant manage to download a specific folder of a specific commit. 
My full git is too big to download the whole project so i need to be able to download only this specific folder. 
If I try to do it throught GUI it start to download and then fail so I can't do like this. 
I tried with command line using

```
    git init
    git remote add origin <url>
    git config core.sparseCheckout true
    echo "some/dir/" >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
    git fetch origin <commit_number>
```

but it doesn't work, it gives me the error :

```
    error: Server does not allow request for unadvertised object <commit_number>
```

How can I do? Thank you

ps: this is not a public project I don't know if it matters

Comment: I tried your sequence of command... and it seems to work...

I saw that you made an error in the second command, but I think that it is just a copy mistake (you missed the `remote` keyword

Comment: other thing is that you have to call 
`git fetch` without a commit_hash (but you should be able to reduce to the last commits with the `--deep` option)
followed by `git checkout <commit_hash>`

Comment: yes, the remote was just a mistake i added it in the question.The problem with git fetch is that it also fail :
`remote: Counting objects: 33519, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (21864/21864), done.
ffatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedlyMiB | 3.54 MiB/s
atal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed`

Comment: Did you try the --deep option? In the case that the commit that you are interested is not too old